# Update Campos tipo fecha sql server desde c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Quiero realizar un update en sql desde una app en c#
Empleo la siguiente consulta

```
sqlFecha = "UPDATE FACTURA SET fecha = '" + fecha + "' where codigo = '" + Convert.ToDecimal(LabelCodFactura.Text) + "'";
                InsertRow(_connectionString, sqlFecha);
```

donde mi variable es:

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;//toma la fecha del equipo
```

pero me enfrento con el siguiente error

> Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora en sql
>   server

el campo en el que quiero actualizar el la fecha es tipo `datetime`

Comment: La primer recomendación es que no uses cadenas concatenadas para enviar comandos SQL, es suceptible a SQL Injection y es un gran fallo de seguridad al que estás expuesto. Incluso, el uso de parámetros en tu codigo C# soluciona el problema que presentas actualmente

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la variable "sqlFormattedDate "?

Comment: Como te comentó @Phi, lo que debes hacer es usar consultas parametrizadas. De esa manera, lo que pasas en tu consulta es el datetime en si, y no una cadena de caracteres, y solucionaras el problema que tienes y otros muchos.

Comment: de verdad un codigo de factura decimal ? los codigo deberian ser int

Comment: gracias @phi por el consejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que funcionalidad realiza `InsertRow()` pero sino permite parámetro deberías adaptarlo o cambiarlo, tu código debería lucir como esto:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))   
{   
    string sqlFecha = "UPDATE FACTURA SET fecha = @fecha where codigo = @codigo";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlFecha, conn);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Now);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", Convert.ToDecimal(LabelCodFactura.Text));    

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Usa siempre parametros que respeten los tipos de datos, si vas asignar una fecha qu sea un datetime no concatnes nunca en un string el valor, si el codigo es numerico no tiene que estar entre comillas simples

Comment: Puedes usar la fecha del servidor de base de datos, poniendo de esta forma tu script sql: "UPDATE FACTURA SET fecha = getdate() where codigo = @codigo", la función  getdate() devuelve la fecha hora actual del servidor.